# Change wordpress theme name (not child theme)

Tags: themes

Is it legal to change the actual name of a wordpress theme (premium or not) to something else (like a client's name for example) so that people won't know what theme is used on a website?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not redistributing your theme, you can name it whatever you want. If you ARE redistributing, you have to abide by the EULA licensing terms of the theme.

Comment: To add to this as well, if you are trying to hide that you are using a theme you will need to change more then just the theme name. You will also need to change the authors name, URL, authors URL, theme thumbnail picture, etc.